# How do I check which PHP extensions my application needs to work?

Tags: php, server, php-extension

I wrote a simple application in PHP. During the development I used XAMPP, and now I want to upload it to a "real" server.

I do not want to install too many extensions on my server. How can I check which extensions my application needs?

Comment: Perhaps this might have your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709843/finding-php-dependencies

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [Please add a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates your issue.

Comment: Not sure what the comments so far mean; the question is pretty clear yet has a difficult answer. There used to be a [package](https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CompatInfo) but it's been long abandoned. No idea if there's a modern replacement.